# Is there Linux system call to provide seconds count since specific date?

Tags: c, linux

For example, I want to count how many seconds I have lived on earth. 
With gettimeofday()/time(), I can get the seconds count since Epoch, what else I want is the diff from  Epoch to my birthday, so my question is is there function like:

```
time_t gettimeof_specified_day(my_birthday);
```

It return the seconds from Epoch to my birthday, then I can use difftime(now, birthday) to get what I want.

Comment: Note that [Epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is not the same as number of seconds since epoch as it omits the leap seconds. Depending on the purpose it might be or might not be a duplicate and answer below might or might not be an answer (it's not a  duplicate and the answer below is incorrect if you ask for the exact number of seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`mktime(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime) function to convert any particular calendar date and time (expressed as a `struct tm` instance) into a `time_t` value:

```
// Convert April 14, 1980 00:00:00 (local time, based on your computer's
// current time zone) into a time_t
struct tm my_birthday;
memset(&my_birthday, 0, sizeof(my_birthday));
my_birthday.tm_year = 80;  // Number of years since 1900
my_birthday.tm_mon = 3;    // Month from 0-11
my_birthday.tm_mday = 14;  // Day of month from 1-31
time_t t = mktime(&my_birthday);
```